# How to can I use a SQL query column in as the arguments of a where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that returns a column with some records:

```
SELECT TAB1.COD FROM TAB1 WHERE COD > 3 AND COD < 7;
```

The query above would return a table like this:

```
_____
|COD|
|---|
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
-----
```

I would like to use the values of the column above in an another query's where clause, like this:

```
SELECT TAB2.ID, TAB2.FOO, TAB2.TAB1COD 
FROM TAB2 
WHERE TAB1COD = 3 OR TAB1COD = 5 OR TAB1COD = 6 OR TAB1COD = 7;
```

I'm not very experienced with SQL, also I'm using Oracle DB if that matters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `IN`, try this

```
SELECT TAB2.ID, TAB2.FOO, TAB2.TAB1COD
FROM TAB2 
WHERE TAB1COD IN (SELECT TAB1.COD 
                   FROM TAB1 
                  WHERE COD > 3 AND COD < 7)
```

**EDIT**: Also a `JOIN` should work for you as suggested by @sgeddes.

Comment: Thanks @user2989408, I think that using `IN` is much easier to understand than using `JOIN`. Also thanks for answer too @sgeddes.

Answer (score 4):

A simple `JOIN` will do the trick:

```
SELECT t2.id, t2.foo, t2.tab1cod
FROM tab2 t2
    JOIN tab1 t1 on t2.tab1cod = t1.cod
WHERE t1.cod > 3 AND t1.cod < 7
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)